# Problem for measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

> Suppose that $A_i$ is a measurable set in $\Bbb R^n$ for each $i$ belonging to an index set $I$, and suppose that the $A_i$'s are disjoint and that $m(A_i)\gt 0$ for all $i$. prove that $I$ is countable

MY Attempt : Since All $A_i$ is disjoint and subset of $\Bbb R^n$ such that there is rational number for each $A_i$. So rational number is countable such $A_i$ is countable. but I can't satisfy second condition $m(A_i)\gt 0$. any help please

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be partitioned into countably many boxes of finite measure. Actually the property is true in any $\sigma$-finite measure space. At least one of them intersects uncountably many of the $A_i$ in positive measure. In fact, you can delete from $A_i$ all the zero measure intersections with the countably many boxes, without changing its measure. Therefore, you can assume that the $A_i$ are inside the boxes they intersect. If each box contains only countably many $A_i$ then there wouldn't be uncountably many of them. Therefore, the problem can be reduced to one of the boxes.

Comment: Assume now that all $A_i$ are inside one of the boxes $B$. We know that $m(B)<\infty$. Now, the numbers $m(A_i)$ are uncountably many counting repetitions. Therefore, there must be a sequence of them $m(A_{i_n})$ converging to some $a\neq 0$. Therefore $\infty>m(B)\leq m(\bigcup_{n}A_{i_n})=\sum_nm(A_{i_n})=\infty$ because $m(A_{i_n})\to a\neq0$. This is a contradiction. Therefore the number of $A_i$ needs to be countable. Notice also we didn't use anything about $\mathbb{R}^n$ besides it being a countable union of subsets of finite measure (that it is $\sigma$-finite).

Comment: What if $\lambda(A_{i})=\infty$ for some $i$? Because $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a measurable set...

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\pr}[1]{\left(#1\right) }$

Hint: let $I_{m,n}$ be the set of all indexes $i$ such that $m\pr{A_i\cap B\pr{0,m}     }\gt 1/n$,  where $B\pr{0,m}$ denotes the ball of center $0$ and radius $m$. Then you have to show that:

1. each $I_{m,n}$ is finite and
2. $\bigcup_{m,n\in\mathbb N}I_{m,n}=I$.

Comment: thank you for your hint, I 'll try